# Creating a pyinstaller executable

Tags: python

I created pyinstaller executable using Python32 on Windows 10 64 bit, but it works only at 64 bit PC (I need to run exe at 32 bit PC).

What should I do, that the program runs at 32 bit PC?

Comment: By Python32 you mean Python version 3.2 or 32 bits? Also, what is the error you get when running on 32 bits machine?

Comment: You'll need the 32-bit versions of any compiled code you're using: Python, NumPy, pyinstaller, what have you. And then you package your code using these 32-bit versions, and not the 64-bit ones.

Comment: 1) I mean 32-bit Python. It gives an error:
"the procedure entry point getfinalpathnamebyhandle could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll"

Comment: 2) As I understand: PyInstaller builds an app using the the word-length of the Python used to execute it. That will typically be a 64-bit version of Python, resulting in a 64-bit executable. To create a 32-bit executable, run PyInstaller under a 32-bit Python. And I checked the version of NumPy - it's 32-bit. I think that the pyinstaller has the same version